# Casting a class into another non hierarchical class form in java

Tags: java, casting

Consider class A

```
class A {
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
}
```

and here is the class B

```
class B {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

**I was wondering if java has any such ting which allows to write/define our own custom casting logic.**

For e.g.
to cast class B's object into class A's object where

> i -> a  // i pointing to value of a
>
> j -> b  // j pointing to value of b
>
> k -> c  // k pointing to value of c

(I can customize the logic to whatever i wish)

I have a few heavy weight objects to "cast" into some other classes to use and i do not want to write a converter method for this.

(casting operates only on the object in consideration and does not create another object)

any thoughts/suggestions for this ?

Thanks in Anticipation !

Comment: You definitely can't do without creating a separate object. Objects can never change classes.

Comment: No. Java does not support duck typing in any way. You can either 1) create a wrapper `class W extends A` which wraps a `B` and does the method calls you described above. or 2) Write a "copy constructor" for `A` which takes a `B` and creates a `new A` with the properties copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This defeats the safety purposes of Java for two reasons.

Let's consider an updated version of your class code.

```
class A {
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int l;
}

class B {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

Now imagine what would happen if you did something like this, assuming the classes were written right above: (Warning:code will not compile)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    B classTwo = new B();
    A classOne = (A) classTwo;
    classOne.l = 3; // <-- what would happen?
}
```

As you can see, it won't work, because creating an instance of B will not allocate the variabls properly. This is why Java **does not** permit casting like that.

What Java does permit is converting between superclasses and subclasses.

For example:

```
class Fruit {
    int i;
}
class Apple extends Fruit {
    int j;
}
```

And now inside the `main` function:
    Fruit f = new Fruit();
    Apple a = (Apple)f; // this compiles, but will raise a ClassCastException

You'll ask, why does it raise a ClassCastException? Apple extends Fruit.

Yes, Apple extends Fruit. But, Fruit does not allocate memory for the `j` variable.

What is allowed is the other way around, casting an Apple to a Fruit, because all Apples have properties of Fruits (even in real life).

If you want to use your idea of casting, you could try an interface.

```
interface C {
    public int getVarOne();
    public int getVarTwo();
    // NO variables here, only functions
}
```

Any class which `implements` (not `extends`) an `interface` must also implement all of the methods defined in it.

Once you've implemented the interface, the behavior is similar to casting to a superclass. There are also other uses for interfaces, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the frameworks like `ModelMapper` ([documentation](http://modelmapper.org/)) to define your maping logic and use it to convert object from one type to object of another type. E.g. this is how the configuration would be:

```
//Model Classes
class A{
    int a;
}
class B{
    int d;
}

//Mappings
PropertyMap<A, B> map = new PropertyMap<A, B>() {
    protected void configure() {
        map(source.a, destination.d);
      }
};

//Test Program
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();

    PropertyMap<A, B> map = new PropertyMap<A, B>() {
        protected void configure() {
            map(source.a, destination.d);
          }
    };
    mapper.addMappings(map);
    A a = new A();
    a.a = 10;
    B b = mapper.map(a, B.class);
    System.out.println(b.d);
}
```

Comment: I am not looking for object conversion(copying values to a new object) !

Comment: @Sumit custom casting is _impossible_ in Java. You'll have to implement a converter. Either by hand or with a helper (like this one) or with clever autogeneration (maybe via annotation processing).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that in my answer but Java does not provide out of the box casting as mentioned by @Andreas_D

Comment: You might be better off with a wrapper rather than a converter. That way the "link" between the original `A` and the `B` is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

No. There's no such thing as unions known from C. You cannot modify the memory directly in JVM. That's the point of Java. It sacrifices some potential for tricks, but in the end the code tends to be less buggy and easier to maintain than the code written in C.

If your concern is memory consumption caused by copying, you can convert `A` and `B` into interfaces. The interfaces should expose getters and setters. For example: `int getI()` and `int getA()`. Then you can introduce a class implementing both of them.
The indirection caused by the interface calls will have some performance cost, but in many cases, it won't be noticable.